# Query to fetch non distinct records from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

Need to know SQL query to fetch data as following

```
TableA
------------------------------------
| CUSTOMER_ID      | ACCOUNT_TYPE   |
_____________________________________
| 1                |  SB            |
| 1                |  SB            |
| 2                |  SB            |
| 2                |  CR            |
| 3                |  CR            |
_____________________________________
```

There is a requirement to fetch rows as follows

```
------------------------------------
| CUSTOMER_ID      | ACCOUNT_TYPE   |
_____________________________________
| 1                |  SB            |
| 1                |  SB            |
| 3                |  CR            |
_____________________________________
```

I need to eliminate the customer_id details which has two different account_type and show only customer_id to which the ACCOUNT type is either same are has only one row.

Can someone help in giving a ORACLE SQL query for this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably tag the question as oracle

Comment: Your sample data looks starnge...for what you are expecting to happen

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried thus far and why it is not working as you would expect?

Comment: Are you sure you want to keep duplicates? It confuses the logic in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I only focused on the following requirements you provided.

> I need to eliminate the customer_id details which has two different
>   account_type and show only customer_id to which the ACCOUNT type is
>   either same are has only one row.

You need to eliminate customer_id details which has two different account_type

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, ACCOUNT_TYPE 
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE COUNT(ACCOUNT_TYPE) > 1 AND COUNT(CUSTOMER_ID) > 1
ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID, ACCOUNT_TYPE;
```

I don't understand your requirements, it is ambiguous. Please revise your statement.